# AWS-SDK Cloudwatch GetMetricData API function not returning data

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to set up a Lambda, using Node.js to query Cloudwatch and get the average # of invocations our Lambdas are using, the goal is that when we are close to reaching our invocation limit that we would trigger a notification to alert us when we are reaching that limit.

I am able to query the CW data, but when I run the script I don't get any data being returned for the period in time.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my script.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();
const webhook = require('send-webhook');
const SSO_URL = "URL1";
const URLS = ['webhook'];

//var endTime = time.Now();
//var duration = time.ParseDuration("-5m");
//var startTime = endTime.Add(duration);

var params = {
  EndTime: '2019-06-04T08:45:00Z',
  MetricDataQueries: [
    {
      Id: 'concurrencycount',
      Label: 'Average concurrency',
      MetricStat: {
        Metric: {
          Dimensions: [
            {
              Name: 'FunctionName',
              Value: 'LambdaName'
            },
          ],
          MetricName: 'Invocations',
          Namespace: 'AWS/Lambda'
        },
        Period: '300',
        Stat: 'Average',
        Unit: 'Count'
      },
      ReturnData: false
    },
  ],
  StartTime: '2019-06-04T08:00:00Z',
  //ScanBy: TimestampDescending
};

//exports.handler = function(event, context){
cloudwatch.getMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else console.log(data)
})
//}
```

When the code runs it isn't returning any data, all I see is the below output that I see.  I've tried with different Lambda functions but I get the same result.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the API call to return that data.

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '291f9049-86ce-11e9-819c-fb65a0786d4d' },
  MetricDataResults: [],
  Messages: [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ReturnData: false` tells cloudwatch to only return the statistics, not the metrics themselves.